# Drupal 6: how to assign more than 1 imagecache to 1 cck field

Tags: image, drupal, drupal-6, cck, drupal-modules

I create few imagecache for

- featured slide img
- standard listing img
- details page thumb and original img

I need to assign all these imagecaches to 1 image that member upload. so It will create all these images from 1 image upload, and I will use them wherever I need. At cck editing part, I can assign only 1 imagecache :/

How can I do that? I googled but could not find anything

Appreciate advises! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

imagecache generates images on-the-fly as they're used for the first time. There's no need to pre-generate them. Any image can be run through any imagecache preset.

CCK's setting only influences how the image will be displayed by default in the node template.

Comment: aha! that makes sense! thanks. so I must find how to use predefined imagecaches in tpl.php files. hmm....